# How do I cancel a completion handler?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I want to enhance the code below: when i click the "submitData" button, the added code should cancel the completion handler.

```
func returnUserData(completion:(result:String)->Void){
  for index in 1...10000 {
     print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")
  }

  completion(result: "END");

}

func test(){
  self.returnUserData({(result)->() in
     print("OK")
  })
}

@IBAction func submintData(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TestView", sender: self)
}
```

Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Is `returnUserData` really doing some loop like this, or is it doing something that might already support cancellation of asynchronous actions (e.g. network request, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSOperation` subclass for this. Put your calculation inside the `main` method, but periodically check `cancelled`, and if so, break out of the calculation.

For example:

```
class TimeConsumingOperation : NSOperation {
    var completion: (String) -> ()

    init(completion: (String) -> ()) {
        self.completion = completion
        super.init()
    }

    override func main() {
        for index in 1...100_000 {
            print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")

            if cancelled { break }
        }

        if cancelled {
            completion("cancelled")
        } else {
            completion("finished successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add the operation to an operation queue:

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue()

let operation = TimeConsumingOperation { (result) -> () in
    print(result)
}
queue.addOperation(operation)
```

And, you can cancel that whenever you want:

```
operation.cancel()
```

This is, admittedly, a fairly contrived example, but it shows how you can cancel your time consuming calculation.

Many asynchronous patterns have their built-in cancelation logic, eliminating the need for the overhead of an `NSOperation` subclass. If you are trying to cancel something that already supports cancelation logic (e.g. `NSURLSession`, `CLGeocoder`, etc.), you don't have to go through this work. But if you're really trying to cancel your own algorithm, the `NSOperation` subclass handles this quite gracefully.